# How to verify that my tmpfs/ramdisk is working?

Tags: mount, ram, tmpfs

I am setting up a RAM disk in CentOS 7, and by all tutorials, I am able to see the speed increase of writing to the disk. However I never see RAM usage increase either from `free -h` or from the System Monitor GUI. Even if I write data to the disk, RAM usage still does not change. Is this RAM disk an illusion?

The command I am using to create the RAM disk is:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=8G myTempFS /mnt/ramdisk
```

and the entry in `/etc/fstab` is:

```
myTempFS  /mnt/ramdisk  defaults,size=8g,x-gvfs-show  0 0
```

Despite all this, RAM usage seems unaffected. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

From `man tmpfs` : **The amount of memory consumed by all tmpfs filesystems is shown in the Shmem field of /proc/meminfo and in the shared field displayed by free(1).**

You can see how much memory each tmpfs mount consume using `df`.